# how to detect view is visible or not in android inside nested scrollview

Tags: android

I have a layout in which we have nested scroll view is parent inside that many views are there I want to detect particular view is visible or not when I launch the Activity or when we go activity to another activity and come back in the same activity  **I don't want on scroll change.**

below is my layout code :

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/cc_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
 
                <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/tv1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="Textview1"
                    android:text="@string/nested_scroll_text"/>
                     <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="Textview2"
                    android:text="@string/nested_scroll_text"/>
                     <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/tv3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="Textview3"
                    android:text="@string/nested_scroll_text"/>
                      <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/tv4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="Textview4"
                    android:text="@string/nested_scroll_text"/>
                     <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/tv5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="Textview5"
                    android:text="@string/nested_scroll_text"/>
                     <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/tv6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="Textview6"
                    android:text="@string/nested_scroll_text"/>
                     <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/tv7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="Textview7"
                    android:text="@string/nested_scroll_text"/>
                     <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/tv8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="Textview8"
                    android:text="@string/nested_scroll_text"/>
 
            </LinearLayout>
 
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

in this layout, I am trying to check if tv1 should be visible when launched or when come back from another activity using the below code I am not getting a solution i am tried below code to check this

```
private fun checkBarCodeSectionVisible() {
        val scrollBounds = Rect()
        cc_scrollview.getHitRect(scrollBounds)
        if (tv1.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
            //visibile
        }
    }
```

but this code not working please help me what i am doing wrong  how to detect particular view is visible or not

Comment: on back  button click just call super.onBackPressed.

Comment: which button click do we have to put super. on back pressed?

Comment: while coming back from second activity to first don't put intent instead put above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // put your code here...

}
```

okey then put this method outside onCreate method and call api again.

Comment: but even on launch activity code is not working my tv1 visibility is hidden but then it also comes inside the condition can you please help me with that?

Comment: i am not getting your question what i get is when you came from second activity to first you don't want to scroll again to that position right?

Comment: Ok let me more clear tv is hidden on API response now i come in activity in on create i call checkBarCodeSectionVisible function which give me  true while it should false because tv is hidden let me know if its not clear